# Javascript heap out of memory permanent solution

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, out-of-memory

I'm having problems running my Vue project due to a JavaScript **Heap out of memory error.**

All solutions that I found in SO are all the same, about increasing the memory `NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096`.

But I don't think this really solves the problem permanently, sooner or later it will soon allocate the increased memory.

Has anyone encountered this error and found a permanent solution?

Comment: Mind there are memory leaks in some node.js versions (even latest sometimes) - you can try another one ;-) While working with fission, default a bit older node.js image had no problems, but when we used latest node...

Comment: How quickly are we talking? during first build or after a week of running? it is a dev tool, not meant to be running forever.